# UWP Using Acrylic in Navigation View

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, acrylic-material

Im looking into the Acrylic options for UWP and have bumped into a strange issue. Essentially, Im trying to get the Navigation view to use a custom Acrylic Brush. However, the main window background is more transparent than the Navigationview. 
I need to get the NavigationView to be as transparent as the current main view. Ive attached an image to help clarify this. Its hard to explain:

[image: Navigation view]

As you can see on the left, the navigation view is not as transparent as the main feature window on the right. I need to swap this around so the NavigationView is more transparent than the MainPage.

Here is my App.XAML

```
<Application
    x:Class="BS.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:BS">
    <Application.Resources>
        <AcrylicBrush x:Key="CustomAcrylicDark"
                      BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop"
                      TintColor="Gray"
                      TintOpacity="0.6"
                      FallbackColor="Black"/>
        <AcrylicBrush x:Key="CustomAcrylicLight"
                      BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop"
                      TintColor="White"
                      TintOpacity="0.6"
                      FallbackColor="White"/>       
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Here is my MainPage.XAML

```
<Page
    x:Class="BS.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:BS"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    RequestedTheme="Dark"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Page.Resources>

    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <NavigationView Background="{StaticResource CustomAcrylicDark}" PaneTitle="BS" IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed" CompactModeThresholdWidth="9999" ExpandedModeThresholdWidth="9999" CompactPaneLength="96">
            <NavigationView.MenuItems>
                <NavigationViewItem Name="HItem" Content="HOME" Tag="HOME_Page" FontSize="22" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="MediumPurple"/>
                <NavigationViewItemSeparator/>
                <NavigationViewItem Name="OItem" Content="OVERVIEW" Tag="O_Page" FontSize="22" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="MediumPurple"/>
                <NavigationViewItem Name="BItem" Content="BILLS" Tag="B_Page" FontSize="22" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="MediumPurple"/>
                <NavigationViewItem Name="PItem" Content="PEOPLE" Tag="B_Page" FontSize="22" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="MediumPurple"/>
                <NavigationViewItem Name="TItem" Content="TRANSFERS" Tag="T_Page" FontSize="22" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="MediumPurple"/>
                <NavigationViewItem Name="PItem" Content="PAY DATES" Tag="P_Page" FontSize="22" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="MediumPurple"/>
            </NavigationView.MenuItems>
        </NavigationView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`NavigationView` is built on top of `Splitview`. In `Splitview`, you will find a property called `PaneBackground` but `NavigationView` won't let you to set the `PaneBackground` property of that `Splitview` it is made on.

But you are not out of luck, upon investigating the template of `NavigationView`, I've found that the `PaneBackground` property is bound to a `ThemeResource` called `NavigationViewDefaultPaneBackground`. So, your job is to override this property. Like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <AcrylicBrush x:Key="NavigationViewDefaultPaneBackground"
                  BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop"
                  TintColor="Gray"
                  TintOpacity="0.6"
                  FallbackColor="Black"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <NavigationView x:Name="Navview" Background="{StaticResource CustomAcrylicDark}" PaneTitle="BS" IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed" 
                    CompactModeThresholdWidth="9999" ExpandedModeThresholdWidth="9999" CompactPaneLength="96">

        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem Name="HItem" Content="HOME" Tag="HOME_Page" FontSize="22" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="MediumPurple"/>
            <NavigationViewItemSeparator/>
            <NavigationViewItem Name="OItem" Content="OVERVIEW" Tag="O_Page" FontSize="22" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="MediumPurple"/>
            <NavigationViewItem Name="BItem" Content="BILLS" Tag="B_Page" FontSize="22" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="MediumPurple"/>
            <NavigationViewItem Name="PItem" Content="PEOPLE" Tag="B_Page" FontSize="22" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="MediumPurple"/>
            <NavigationViewItem Name="TItem" Content="TRANSFERS" Tag="T_Page" FontSize="22" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="MediumPurple"/>
            <NavigationViewItem Name="PItem2" Content="PAY DATES" Tag="P_Page" FontSize="22" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="MediumPurple"/>
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="{x:Bind Navview.DisplayMode, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </NavigationView>
</Grid>
```

This gives the result below:
[image]

So, you can set the pane's background as you wish using this method. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for this

Comment: glad to help you :)

Comment: Is it possible to change `TintColor` dynamically, based on theme(black/white)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PaneDisplayMode="Left" then override  NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackground

```
<AcrylicBrush x:Key="NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackground"
                  BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop"
                  TintColor="Gray"
                  TintOpacity="0.6"
                  FallbackColor="Black"/>
```

here is link from Microsoft docs
 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview#customizing-backgrounds